# Регулярные выражения. Php - поиск email

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь разобраться с регулярным выражением, которое ищет почту.

```
$text = 'foo foo@bar.lol bar lol baz baz@qwe.asdf qwe asdf';
if (preg_match_all('~[-a-z0-9_]+(?:\\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*@[-a-z0-9]+(?:\\.[-a-z0-9]+)*\\.[a-z]+~i', $text, $M, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach ($M as $m) {
        echo $m[0] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
else echo 'not found';
```

Но не могу понять несколько моментов:

1. `(?:\\.` - одна часть экранирует точку,а первая со знаком вопроса и двоеточием?
2. `*@` - эта часть просто говорит, что до "собаки" любой символ?
3. `[-a-z0-9_]+(?:\\.[-a-z0-9_]+)` - почему одна часть сгруппирована, а другая нет?

Comment: Что тут не работает? В чём проблема?

Comment: Код рабочий, ниже кода вопросы, которые не могу для себя прояснить. . (?:\. - одна часть экранирует точку,а первая со знаком вопроса и двоеточием? 2. *@ - эта часть просто говорит, что до "собаки" любой символ? 3. [-a-z0-9_]+(?:\.[-a-z0-9_]+) - почему одна часть сгруппирована, а другая нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `(?:...)` - незахватываемая группа. Используется что бы применить квантификатор `*` (0 и больше раз) к группе, отличается от обычной группировки `(...)` тем, что не создает ссылку и не занимается память, актуально если мы не планируем переиспользовать группу.
2. `*` - это квантификатор, как написано уже в первом пункте, он относится к группе `(?:\\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*` и означает, что эта группа может повториться 0+ раз
3. `[-a-z0-9_]+(?:\\.[-a-z0-9_]+)` - тут сложнее сказать, скорее всего из-за точки, так как перед `@` должен стоять символ отличный от точки.